# Difference between useState with (current => current + 1) and useState(value + 1);

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the difference between two ways of using `useState`? I noticed only one triggers re-render.

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
```

1. Doesn't trigger re-render/UI change:

   ```
   setIndex(index + 1);
   ```
2. Triggers re-render/UI change:

   ```
   setIndex((currentIndex) => currentIndex + 1);
   ```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: As for the first point about *not* updating, see [bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update). Perhaps due to the evaluated value of `index + 1` resulted in it being the value as the existing state and so the rerender was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no relevant difference for most use cases, and **both methods should trigger a re-render** as the state value changes in both cases.

Although, React's state (updating) actually works asynchronously under the hood, and by using the callback function: `setIndex((currentIndex) => currentIndex + 1);` you ensure to always update the **latest value** of "currentIndex" by 1.

When using `setIndex(index + 1);` too quickly after changing the state, `index` may still refer to the **old** value because the last change hasn't been executed yet.

Edit: Hence, when updating the state too quickly without using the callback function, you may set the state to the value it already has, which would not trigger a re-render of function components (which you may be experiencing). From what I know, it would still trigger a re-render of class components though.

Comment: I see so that's why my component wasn't updating or appeared to not update, I was just setting it to same value with 1 way.